# how to video broadcast online to my web site ?

Tags: video-streaming

I want to make a system  that uploads a video to my website at a specific time as a live stream.

I want to know what are the best servers and if there is any providers for this service.

Answer (score 2):

Simple enough, you could just use [YouTube's live stream](https://support.google.com/youtube/answer/2474026?hl=en) feature and just embed the YouTube Player Object (Iframe) on your website. I believe you can have the YT encoder default to some sort of preview video or count down until the live stream is ready.